# What type of network traffic does not use Winsock in Windows?

Tags: windows, winsock, smb, icmp

I am developing some low-level stuff (LSP) and found out, that SMB traffic does not go through LSP, because SMB does not use Winsock. There is a paragraph in MSDN about it, but this is in part of MSDN dedicated to Windows CE. So, is there any comprehend list of whole traffic that does not go through Winsock? MSDN is bit messy about that.

I have found now:

1. SMB
2. ICMP

Answer (score 2):

Interesting - I'd always assumed that everything went via winsock.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885820.aspx) (I trust this isn't simply the same info you already found):

> Note   Because the following protocols and technologies do not use the Winsock LSP model, you cannot modify them by writing an LSP:
>
> - DHCP, ICMP, and IGMP and **other layer
>     3 protocols** [my emphasis]
> - DNS proxy
> - Redirector
> - SMB server

What I can't deduce from that MSDN link is whether "other layer 3 protocols" means exactly that or "all other layer 3 protocols".

However, [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245442) describes how ICMP Port Unreachable messages are ignored by Winsock - on certain (very old) platforms - I wonder if the networking portion of CE has not been updated...